# Windows 10 blocking applications without asking for permission

Tags: windows, windows-10, permissions

I have a problem with Windows 10 blocking applications from making changes. I remember previously it showed popups asking for permissions, now I'm just getting the notifications that the application was blocked.

What's even worse is that quite often in the notification the application name gets truncated and it's impossible to tell the exact application so I could add another exclusion.

(Different language but you get the point)

[image]

It is causing updates to fail and programs malfunction (Adobe Lightroom, for example)

I want it to simply ask for permission not that I have to guess the exact program file and add it as an exception every time.